# CSS dropdown menu doesn't work in IE and Firefox

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I've been looking around for a solution and didnt find anything. Therefore I am asking a question.
The drop down menu works in Chrome in my computer and other devices (computers and laptops) at home. Except in Firefox and IE.

```
#menu {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;  
bottom: 85.125%;
z-index: 100;

height: 100px;
margin-top: -200px;

width: 300px;
margin-left: -150px;
 }

 ul {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
 }

  ul#nav li {
background: #fff;
float: left;
  }

 ul#nav li a {
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
color: #000;
padding: 5px 15px;
 }

 ul#nav li a:hover {
background: #aaa;
 }

 ul#nav li ul li {
float: none;
 }
 ul#nav li ul {
position: absolute;
display: none;
 }
 ul#nav li:hover ul {
display:block;
 }

 body {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
  }




      <body>
        <header>
                <!-- input for header text-->
        </header>


        <div id="menu">
        <!-- input for the navigation menu -->
            <ul id="nav">
                <li><a href="hem.html" id="hem">Hem</a></li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#" id="browsers">Browsers</a>
                    <ul>
            <li><a href="chrome.html">Chrome</a></li>
            <li><a href="firefox.html">Firefox</a></li>
            <li><a href="ie.html">IE</a></li>
            <li><a href="opera.html">Opera</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

            <li><a href="data.html" id="data"> Data</a></li>
            <li><a href="synpunkt.html" id="synpunkt">Synpunkt</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
   </body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Two reasons,

1) Your HTML has an error, these lines --

```
    <li><a>href="chrome.html">Chrome</a></li>
    <li><a>href="firefox.html">Firefox</a></li>
```

should be

```
    <li><a href="chrome.html">Chrome</a></li>
    <li><a href="firefox.html">Firefox</a></li>
```

And

2) Your `ul` has id `navbar`, but in css you're using `#nav` as the selector. So either change the id or change the selector in css.

Check the [Test Link](http://jsfiddle.net/PJSP5/5/)

**EDIT: Screenshots !! :)**

Firefox:
[image]

IE9:
[image]

if this is not correct, please explain what is not correct.

Comment: Yes i have edited it now. I forgot to check the code before i asked a question. The problem is still there.

Comment: Can you explain what "not working" means? the code works fine on IE10 and FX (latest) .. Are you targeting any specific version of IE and FX?

Comment: It should look like this, Chrome - http://imgur.com/zp3Jtc2,xaAHRgW and in IE and Firefox it looks like this http://imgur.com/zp3Jtc2,xaAHRgW#1

Comment: The code gives me in Chrome nice smooth looking buttons with drop down and in IE it just dont render the CSS. The output is in left top corner.

Comment: Which version of IE are you testing this in?

Comment: Check this -- http://jsfiddle.net/PJSP5/6/ .. This works fine in IE9, also, be sure that your browser is set to 100% zoom level (not less/more). You can do that by hittin `ctrl + 0`

Comment: Still a problem. I tried and it works from using jsfiddle.net .. but why does it not work in Firefox and IE?

Comment: The code works, indepedent software browser rendering problem?

Comment: So, the way you're writing you css is not ideal, remove the `bottom` property of `#menu` from the css and use `top` instead, and have a wrapping div around it Also remove the inline style from `#navbar`

Comment: It got worse. It works in jsfiddle.net but not as independent css file.

Comment: Can you post some screenshots, will give me a better idea, meanwhile let me try moving this out to independent files and check

Comment: Have you tried to save the code as html and css. It will not render it as like jsfiddle.net

Comment: The suggestion you posted in jsfiddle.net it looks like the screenshots i uploaded in the earlier comments (look up).

Comment: Hey, I've updated my answer with screenshots from FX and IE9, please check

Comment: Clear you cache/history and restart your browser. That might help. And nope, no changes to the code this is the one I'm using - jsfiddle.net/PJSP5/7

Comment: Check your screen resolution, browser zoom level. post some screenshots and I get a better idea.

Comment: Fix the markup, use a *css reset*, use proper `doctype`. That will help

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is broken:

```
        <li><a>href="chrome.html">Chrome</a></li>
        <li><a>href="firefox.html">Firefox</a></li>
```

should be

```
        <li><a href="chrome.html">Chrome</a></li>
        <li><a href="firefox.html">Firefox</a></li>
```

But I can't get this working in Chrome anyway. Can you replicate the issue in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Check my answer, there's an error in the css selector as well.

Comment: Sorry. The html and css is fixed now, but still a problem!

Comment: @badZoke yep good work. Your version is working fine for me in Firefox.

Comment: Thank you. Have you modified your Firefox? Because it doesnt render it all in my Firefox.

Comment: Im using the latest Firefox version. Firefox 21.0

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code for css, in ie press f12 and make sure that browser mode and document mode is both set to ie9.

EDIT: Header should look like this.

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset=utf-8>
    <title>Index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>



#menu 
     {
         position: relative;
         top: 50px;
         left: 800px;
         display: inline-block;
     }

ul 
    {


list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

ul#nav li 

    {
        background: #fff;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
    }

ul#nav li a 

    {
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        color: #000;
        padding: 5px 15px;
    }

ul#nav li a:hover 

    {
        background: #aaa;
    }

ul#nav li > ul li 

    {
        float: none;
    }

ul#nav li > ul 

    {
        left: 3px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 29px;
        display: none;
    }

ul#nav li:hover ul {
        display:block;
    }

body 

    {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }
```

Comment: No solution, still a problem.

Comment: Then your css is not being red properly, you didn't import it as you should. Use this header and make sure you have some folder, html file and css folder put in that main folder, and in css folder put your css file, I called it style.